# Multiple Plots in the Same Figure [R]

Tags: r, data-visualization

I would like to plot two functions f1 and f2 on the same graph. With the following code, I found that the scale of the y axes for the two plots are different. Is there a way to make the scales same?

```
plot(f1, 0, 1)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(f2, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `curve` function:

```
plot(f1, 0, 1)
curve(f2, 0, 1, add=TRUE)
```